# Car rpm unstable when idling

Tags: rpm

Car's rpm keeps dropping below 1k an then climbs up to 1.5k and the process repeats and repeats.
It happens when i turn on the AC but when i turn the AC off it seems to be more stable.
Some people say that this is caused by a bad throttle body.
Is this true or maybe its other causes?

Comment: idle hunting is usually due to a very dirty throttle body, it needs a good cleaning.

Comment: @Moab maybe you should post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Idle hunting is usually due to a very dirty throttle body, it needs a good cleaning.

Depending on make and model you may have to perform idle relearn after cleaning.

Comment: Also check fuel pressure. And tiny splits in a vacuum hose can open and close.